# View based NSTableView text field loses focus

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

After selecting a row, pressing TAB will normally move focus to the next editable text field(s), or in my case, column.  However, I have noticed that only sometimes after pressing TAB, the row will turn gray and focus is lost.  I must then click on the text field to continue.  After days of observations, I still cannot detect a repeatable pattern, and internet searches have not given me enough information.  I wonder if my delegate might be the culprit.  Some questions come to mind.

1. Can anyone shed light on why or how focus might be lost? (indirectly answered by Willeke's comment to remove some code)
2. Is there a proper or deliberate way to force focus on the next text field? (now irrelevant)
3. The unpredictable behavior prompting the first two questions seemed to be interference between two methods.  Resolving one has at least led to predictable behavior and this related question.  I included more code below with another method.  One column contains a pop-up button.  Ordinarily, choosing a value does not select the row (ie, highlighted).  I would like the row to be selected and focused (ie, highlighted blue) so that I can immediately TAB to the next field and begin editing.  In `editPopUps:`, `selectRowIndexes:` will select the row, but the row is gray instead of blue and hence TAB has no effect.  How do I select and focus the row?

Update: Here are some pertinent methods.  I setup each view based on column because only some columns are editable.

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSString *column = tableColumn.identifier;
    NSTableCellView *value = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:column owner:self];

    Foo *foo = self.foos[row];
    [self setupView:value column:column foo:foo];
    [self populateCellView:value column:column foo:foo object:[foo valueForKey:column]];

    return value;
}

- (void)setupCellView:(NSTableCellView *)view column:(NSString *)column foo:(Foo *)foo {
    view.textField.alignment = NSRightTextAlignment;
    BOOL editable = YES;
    if ([attribute isEqualToString:column] || ![foo.x isEqualToNumber:bar.x]) {
        editable = NO;
    } else {
        view.textField.target = self;
        view.textField.action = @selector(editTextField:);
    }
    [view.textField setEditable:editable];
}

- (void)editTextField:(NSTextField *)sender {
    if ([self.fooTableView numberOfSelectedRows]) {
        NSTableCellView *cellView = (NSTableCellView *)[sender superview];
        NSString *column = cellView.identifier;
        NSInteger row = [self.fooTableView rowForView:cellView];
        Foo *foo = self.foos[row];
        NSNumber *amountNumber = [NSNumber numberWithShort:[sender intValue]];
        if ([attribute isEqualToString:column]) {
            foo.y = amountNumber;
        } else {
            foo.z = amountNumber;
        }

        [self.fooTableView reloadDataForRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:row] columnIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[self.fooTableView columnWithIdentifier:column]]];
        [self refreshSelection];
    }
}

- (void)editPopUps:(NSPopUpButton *)sender {
    GlorpView *glorpView = (GlorpView *)[sender superview];
    NSString *column = pokeCellView.identifier;
    NSInteger row = [self.fooTableView rowForView:glorpView];
    Foo *foo = self.foos[row];
    NSNumber *indexValue = [NSNumber numberWithShort:[sender indexOfSelectedItem]];
    NSMutableIndexSet *columnIndexes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[self.fooTableView columnWithIdentifier:column]];

    if ([attribute isEqualToString:column]) {
        foo.Z = indexValue;
    }

    [self.fooTableView selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:row] byExtendingSelection:NO];
    [self refreshSelection];
}
```

Comment: 1. Show us your datasource and delegate code. 2. Yes there is, but you should fix the bug.

Comment: What happens if you remove `reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:` and `refreshSelection`?

Comment: @Willeke, `refreshSelection` is harmless, but `reloadData` was unnecessary and causing unpredictable behavior.  However, my ultimate goal is still unsolved.  Thanks for the hint in the right direction and for any insight into my updated question.

Comment: Selecting the row in the action method of the popup button should work. Maybe the table view lost focus. What does `refreshSelection` do? Do you want the popup button to be focused?

Comment: @Willeke, ah, somehow you reminded me of first responder, and that was the trick.  Table behavior is much more predictable now.  This also led me to another minor irritation, but that might be a separate question.  I am pretty happy to be 99% of the way there, thanks.